# Cordova IOS app store rejection (app doesn't use native features)

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have built an angular 6 app with a splash screen with Cordova and deployed successfully to the android play store, however I get the following rejection from the IOS app store when I submit the same web code in a cordova app:

- Your app did not include iOS features. App Store apps should use native iOS buttons and include iOS features other than just web views, push notifications, or sharing.

It appears it won't pass the review process as a webview only app, however I thought this is what Cordova is for! Is there anything else I can do to make it pass the app store review? Add other native plugins?

I don't want to move off Cordova as it looks great technology.

Google play app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.footballmatcher.app

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks
Steve

Comment: Cordova lets you use web technologies to develop cross-platform apps, but Apple's store guidelines require that your app do more than could be achieved with a simple web site, or as seems to be the case here, simply presents an existing web site in an app;  iOS has an app that does that called Safari.  It may be that your application just isn't suitable for delivery as an iOS app. To be clear, you could develop this app in Swift and if it just presented your web site in a web view it would still be rejected.

Comment: thanks @paulw11 - is there anyway of getting cordova to do more than the webview and pass in the app store? has anyone got a cordova app into the store?

Comment: There are plenty of Cordova apps in the app store. If your app simply displays an existing web site in a web view it isn't suitable for the app store; Ask yourself, aside from the splash screen is the any difference in functionality between your app and simply opening your web site in Safari; if the answer is "no" then your app isn't suitable for the app store.

Comment: thanks paul - that's good news. We have native features we'd want to implement like geolocation, push notifications, local storage etc. We just haven't implemented it yet as we didn't want to go down the Cordova route unless we could get a prototype in the app store. So if we implemented those features via cordova plugins, do you think they would accept it?

Comment: Maybe. Only Apple can say